# Error building wheel for nudepy for Imago

Tags: image, python-wheel, computer-forensics

Failed building wheel for nudepy.

I'm trying to install Imago Forensics https://github.com/redaelli/imago-forensics but the `pip install imago` function reports the error **Failed building wheel for nudepy**

I'm using the latest version of python.
Thank you in advance.

I tried installing as per the read me, I tried a manual install of nudepy but with no success.